# Ubuntu 12.04.3 won't install/run on mint16 machine

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I'm a complete newbie.  Installed linux mint 16 3 weeks ago but I find it difficult to find answers for this distro - nearly always google gives me ubuntu answers to try.  I've just burnt a dvd with Ubuntu 12.04.3 but my desktop after asking me what system I want to boot into just opens up in Mint 16. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to select your DVD device in Boot Device selection on boot.

Answer (score 1):

When the computer boots, you have to press F2, F12, Enter, etc *(it varys by manufacturer)*, to select 'Boot Device Selection'. It may looks something like this: [image: this]

Select your DVD device from the list - it may begin with CD, DVD, or the name of its manufacturer.